# PHP file_get_contents not capturing all html?

Tags: php

I am using the `file_get_contents`

```
$html = file_get_contents(http://www.telegraph.co.uk/search/?queryText=%22tony%20blair%22&type=relevant&sort=date%3AD%3AL%3Ad1&startIndex=10&site=default_collection&version=);
```

But am having a problem. If I paste this web address into a browser and view source I can see all of the articles. However when you view the source that is captured via `file_get_contents` then it only seems to have captured the header and the footer of the site and missed everything in the middle which is the main part that I need.

Could anyone offer any advice on this?

Many Thanks

Mike

Comment: If that content is generated by javascript you won't be able to scrape their data this way

Comment: to add to @JohnConde if you want to get content that is generated by Javascript you need to use PhantomJS or another alternative.

Comment: You folks do realize that he's tagged this with php and made no mention of using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** This isn't a complete answer, but the comments field isn't rich enough to support this detailed analysis. Once more information is provided, I'll update or delete this answer.

If I run this in php (note the use of "" around the url!):

```
$html = explode("\n", file_get_contents("http://www.telegraph.co.uk/search/?queryText=%22tony%20blair%22&type=relevant&sort=date%3AD%3AL%3Ad1&startIndex=10&site=default_collection&version="));
echo count($html);
```

...it results in `703`. Viewing the source lines count on the site in Chrome shows `709`.

Admittedly this **does not** answer your question, however we can conclude that that your problem does not lie with the code snippet you provided. Are you able to provide more of your codebase?

Additionally, you'll have much more success (and control) using [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) to perform this `GET` request than you would with `file_get_contents`.

Comment: Hi sorry. I'm quite new to this. I'm not sure if the file is generated with Java script? Would anyone be able to tell what code I require to capture all of the code from this site so I have the same that I can see by viewing source. Thanks.